# Extraction of nickel from its ores

Tags: metal, transition-metals, extraction

How is nickel mined and extracted from its ores?

What are the appropriate word and chemical equations for this process?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nickel can be extracted directly from its ore by reduction by hydrogen or carbon monoxide at elevated temperature at $600\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ to $650\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$:

$$\ce{NiO + H2 -> Ni + H2O}$$

$$\ce{NiO + CO -> Ni + CO2}$$

Also, it can be extracted by treatment with dilute sulfuric acid following by precipitation:

$$\ce{NiO + 2H+ -> Ni^2+ + H2O}$$